# In what sense does a hyperbolic space have more information capacity than an Euclidean one?

Tags: mathematical-physics, information-theory, hyperbolic-geometry, statistical-mechanics

Sorry for the dumb hand-wavy question, but I'm looking for a concept but I don't quite know what to look for.

It's sometimes mentioned that a hyperbolic space is in some sense "bigger" than a Euclidean space, but I'm looking for something a bit more solid.  In particular, I am looking for a concept (e.g. volume entropy) which shows that, say, a ball $B(r)$ in $H^3$ can "store" more information than a ball in $E^3$.

[edit]
**Volume Entropy and Information Capacity:**

As it's suggested below, we know that volume of a ball $V(B(r))$ in $H^3$ is larger than $V(B(r))$ in $E^3$ for any radius $r$, so I guess we can go ahead and say that the number of states in a given volume is proportional [1] to $V(B(r))$ and its information capacity is equal to its entropy $S = k \ln V$.

If this is true, then the volume entropy 
$h = \lim_{r \to + \infty} \frac{\ln(V(B(r))}{r}$ is a measure of asymptotic information *density* of the entire space.

[1] or is it proportional to the surface area? Or does that only apply to black holes? I really don't know anything about information theory or statistical mechanics, so very much appreciate any pointers.

**Related Question: Entropy in $S^3$:**

*(let me know if this should be a new question)*

What if we apply the concept of volume entropy to a ball in $S^3$.  If $r$ gets too big, then it wraps around again, but we've already covered all the volume in $S^3$ and hence $V(B(r))$ is bounded by the (finite) volume of $S^3$, $V_{max}$. So does this mean we can say, that $h = \lim_{r \to + \infty} \frac{\ln(min[(V(B(r)),V_{max}])}{r} = 0$?

(I'm sure this must be textbook material for cosmology majors who have to think about entropy in AdS, but I have no physics training at all, so appreciate any further advice!)

Comment: This comment is in jest but if you can tile Hyperbolic $2$ space with regular octogons but not Euclidean $2$ space, surely the former has more "room"( for a suitably hand-wavy notion of "room") right?

Comment: Well, a ball of a given radius has bigger surface area in hyperbolic space than in Euclidean space. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: @Arthur and volume too.

Comment: Thanks everyone, really appreciate the pointers (even jokes) because it does help me to think about the problem.  I've narrowed it down a little and I'm going to run with the idea of size as entropy (not just volume or surface area) so appreciate any further comments!